# Smartsheet access in a azure function

Tags: c#, azure, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Ok so I have a litle bit of a problem. I'm create some azure functions and need to add some data from a smartsheet when it loads, it's a pretty old programm( netstandard 2.0) I have smartsheet nuget package installed to 2.126.0

Here is the message I recived:

> Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_FollowRedirects(Boolean)

Here is how i get the sheet:

`var accessToken = "accesscode"; SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(accessToken).Build();`

When I try to run the same code in a normal c# solution enviroment it works so is just in the azure function enviorment it keeps failing.

Comment: what version of azure function, restsharp and NewtonsoftJson are you using ?
Some binding redirects may be needed.

Comment: im using restharp 107.3.0 and newtonsoft 12.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by changing the restsharp to version to 106.6.9, I think because of the newer version having to many dependencies on other pacakges it just would not work, when i changed restsharp to an earlier version it worked at once.